# split integer, float and Chinese character with Python

Tags: python, numpy

Here is the raw data.

```
[['9河北36010.27'],
 ['10福建35804.04'],
 ...
 ['23黑龙江16361.62']]
```

Each string consists of 3 parts which are id, province name and GDP value.

This code is to extract data from the raw

```
provc_list = []
gdp_list = []
for i in raw:
    match_1 = re.match('\d{1,9}', i[0])
    stw_provc = i[0][match_1.end():]
    match_2 = re.search('\d{1,9}', stw_provc)
    provc_list.append(stw_provc[:match_2.start()])
    gdp_list.append(stw_provc[match_2.start():])
```

then I got

```
['广东', '江苏', '山东']
['97277.77', '92595.4', '76469.67']
```

the code works well as expected. Is there more elegant/graceful/refined code to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
>>> a = [['9河北36010.27'],
...   ['10福建35804.04'],]
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> re.findall( r'(\d+)([^\d]+)([0-9.]+)', a[0][0])
[('9', '河北', '36010.27')]
>>>
```